# Count subdocuments for each document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to just count subdocuments in Mongo for each document.

It's easy to get documents in a collection with `db.users.find().length()`. I want to do something similar like `db.users.projects.find().length()`. How can I do this?

Edit:

The result I want is to know how many projects each user has... So something like:

`{_id: 123, projects: 4}`

Example user document:

```
{
   _id:{$oid: 123},
   username: johnsmith,
   projects: [{$oid: 456}, {$oid: 789}]
}
```

Comment: I think you probably want to use db.users.find().count() instead but aside from that, could you supply 2 or 3 docs as examples?   It's not completely clear what behavior you want out counting subdocuments, esp. if the subdoc contains arrays.

Comment: Oops, yes - `.count()` is what I meant. Will edit the question to include more info.

Answer (score 13):

Per @n9code, you will need the Aggregation Framework. However, you can very easily count the sub-documents with `$size`:

```
db.users.aggregate([{
  $project: {
    _id: '$_id',
    totalProjects: { $size: "$projects" }
  }
}]);
```

Which should return something like this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectID(...), "totalProjects" : 89 }, ...
```

[$size](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) will return the length of the `projects` array for each document and [$project](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) changes the format of the documents to include `totalProjects` as the size of the `projects` array.

Comment: ah sorry, I don't think my question was clear enough. I meant to say I need to count projects that each user owns. See edit.

Comment: @sanjaypoyzer No, it wasn't clear and it definitely changes the answer. The update should get you want you want. With `$project`, you can also return whatever other fields you want.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you may have multiple username docs in your design, e.g.

```
{ username: "buzz", projects: [ list of 2 things ] }
{ username: "dan". projects: [ list of 3 things ] }
{ username: "buzz", projects: [ list of 4 things ] }
```

To arrive at the "grant total" of projects for each `username` try this:

```
c = db.foo.aggregate([
{$project: {
    "username": 1,
    "n": {$size: "$projects"}
}
}
, 
{$group: {
    "_id": "$username",
    "alln": {$sum: "$n"}
}
}
]);
```

to yield

```
{ "_id" : "buzz", "alln" : 6 }
{ "_id" : "dan", "alln" : 3 }
```

Answer (score 0):

A better approach for counting sub-document using mongoose using [VirtualType()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/virtualtype.html)
Let us understand this by a simple example using Blogpost and Comment schema design

```
const Blogpost = new Schema({
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    body: { type: String, required: true },
    userId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true },
    commentId: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment' }],
    lastModifiedAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
})


const Comment = new Schema({
    postId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Post', required: true },
    userId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true },
    text: { type: String, required: true },
    lastModified: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
})
```

Now, if we have to get the totalComments for every blog post then we have to create a VirtualType in Blogpost schema design

```
Blogpost.virtual('totalComments', {
    ref: 'Comment', // model to use for matching
    localField: '_id', // from `localField` i.e., Blogpost
    foreignField: 'postId', // is equal to `foreignField` of Comment schema
    count: true //only get the number of docs
});

Blogpost.set('toObject', { virtuals: true });
Blogpost.set('toJSON', { virtuals: true });
```

As we have postId in Comment schema that holds the Blogpost._id which is associated with that particular Blogpost then only we are able to match and get the totalComments for every Blogpost

Now using population we can get the totalComments for every Blogpost

```
let blogpost = await Blogpost.model
    .find({})
    .populate({ path: 'totalComments', count: true })
```

Answer (score -1):

You need MongoDB's [**`Aggregation Framework`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/) here:

```
db.users.aggregate({$unwind: '$projects'}).count()
```

This will unwind the `projects` array field in each document of your collection, which will be the total number of `projects` subdocuments.

Comment: At first glance, this looks like it should work, but you can't use `count` like this as it returns a `TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'count'`. To count the results, you need to use the `$group` stage and count the documents or do it at the application level. However, per my answer below, there is no need to unwind all of the sub-documents.

Comment: In mongo shell the result of aggregation query is a `cursor` object, which has the `count()` method. So please run the query there and then reconsider your downvote.

Comment: I didn't vote on your post, but I did run this in my shell (v2.6) and the error I posted was the output. Perhaps it works as you say on later versions. While this may do the job, I still wouldn't recommend it because of the `$unwind`.

Comment: On MongoDB version v4.2.8, this still throws `TypeError: (...).count is not a function`.